# Convert plain text into <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple **readonly** textboxes like this

```
<div id="box">
<form method="post" action="">
<input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="1" value="A"  border="0" />
<input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="2" value="B"  border="0" />
<input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="3" value="C"  border="0" />
<input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="4" value="D"  border="0" />
<input  type="button" value="EDIT" />
</form>
</div>
```

I want to convert this **readonly** textboxes into **Editable** Textboxes with **borders** on clicking
Edit button.

How can I achieve this using JQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution here, http://jsfiddle.net/NXCBQ/1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit-button").click(function() {
        $(".someClass").each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
            $(this).addClass("borders");
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
input.borders {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

untested but:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('readonly').attr('border', '1');
});
```

EDIT:
I would rather put border with:

```
.css('border', '1px solid #000')
```

instead of

```
.attr('border', '1')
```

Comment: If my left wrist wasn't broken, I would have beat you to it :)

Comment: lol my partner on my left at work is in the same situation.. I'm an opportunist you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
  $("input[type=text]").removeAttr("readonly").removeAttr("border");
});
```